# Получение данных из компонента TGrid в Embarcardero RAD Studio XE5

Tags: radstudio, c++builder-xe, c++

Имеется компонент TGrid с одной колонкой TPopupColumn. Необходимо получить данные из n-ой ячейки в данной колонке. В C++ Builder 6 получение данных осуществлялось через Grid->Cells[row][col], сейчас не могу понять как. 
С уважением, maxspb.

Comment: Если Вы имеете ввиду TStringGrid, то именно так как Вы написали. Я только что закончил проект с формой, включающей этот компонент, и никаких затруднений не испытал.

Comment: Нет, я имею ввиду TGrid, доступ к нему организуется через OnGetValue и OnSetValue, но каким образом я так и не понял.